# Let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $\int_{-1}^{1} x^{2n}f(x) dx = 0$, what can you say about f?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
 be a continuous function. If $\int_{-1}^{1} x^{2n}f(x) dx = 0$, for all $n = 0,1,2,..$ what can you say about f?

I have seen a similar proof for $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n}f(x) dx = 0$ where f =0, but I am lost for this one. In a similar proof, they used the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: Can you think of a function with this property that is not identically $0$?

Comment: A function such that $f(x) = x^n$ where n is odd power

Comment: Exactly, big clue there.

Comment: So, $ f = 0$ or $ x^n $ where n is odd

Comment: No, there are more, try to think of some other examples and see what they have in common.

Comment: A little more general.  $f = x^n + x^m$ where, $m,n$ are both odd would work, or $f(x) = \sin x$....What do these functions have in common?  There is a name for these sorts of functions.

Comment: they are odd functions, but isn't f(x) = x+1 odd? this odd function does not work.

Comment: $f(x) = x+1$ is not odd.

Comment: okay so i guess, f = 0 or any odd function. my problem is proving this.

Comment: Hint, look at the [even-odd decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even%E2%80%93odd_decomposition) of $f$